# Transforming/reshaping a dataset : Ranking College football teams for the last 50 years

Tags: regex, r, transform

I need some help transforming my dataset. I would appreciate any help or feedback.

[image: What I currently have]

[image: What I'm trying to get]

I have data of College football scores for the last 50 years. I currently have a data frame like in picture 1, and I need to get a data frame similar to picture 2. The data frame I'm trying to get needs to have a concatenated list of all teams played each year, and also two columns that keep track of wins an losses respectively. The concatenated list must be specific for each year. So basically a data frame like picture 2, but has data for every year separately.

This is the code to get a cleaned up dataframe similar to the one I have in picture one.

```
# Make generic data frame and get data

practice = data.frame('a'=character(), 'b'=character(), 'c'= numeric(), 'd'=character(), 'e'= numeric(), 'f'=character())
widths = c(10, 28, 5, 28, 3, 19)
years = 1960:2010
for (i in years){
  football_page = paste('http://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~dwilson/rsfc/history/howell/cf', i, 'gms.txt',sep = '')
  get_data = read.fwf(football_page, widths)
  practice = rbind(practice, get_data)
}

heading = list('DATE', 'AWAY TEAM', 'AWAY SCORE', 'HOME TEAM', 'HOME SCORE', 'LOCATION')
colnames(practice) = heading


# Fixing season dates

practice = cbind('SEASON'=numeric(nrow(practice)),practice)
fix_date = matrix(0, nrow = nrow(practice))
for (j in 1:nrow(fix_date)){
  fix_date[j,1] = substr(practice[j,2],7,10)
}
fix_date = as.numeric(fix_date)
practice$SEASON = fix_date
for (j in 1:nrow(practice)){
  if (grepl('01/.......', practice[j,2]))
    practice[j,1] = practice[j,1]-1 
}


#fix names

practice[,3]=gsub(' ','',practice[,3])
practice[,5]=gsub(' ','',practice[,5])


#drop location and columns

practice = practice[, -7]
practice = practice[, -2]
```

The data set is called practice.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this. I would probably use `dplyr` and write a function that filters the data for a single team (home or away), groups by year, and computes and sums wins and losses. You could `lapply` that function to a vector of unique team names and then merge the resulting list into a single data frame. What have you tried that hasn't worked?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm only allowed to use code from base R, unfortunately, so I can't use dplyR. I've tried a lot of different things, and managed to get the correct results for only one year, but as soon as I try do it for numerous years the computing time grows exponentially and gives me strange results. Do you want to see the code?

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how you would use dplyr? @ulfelder

Comment: The wins and losses should be relatively straightforward. You basically just need to add `winning_team` and `losing_team` helper columns and create tables on those columns and then do a merge. 

Presumably you also have another data frame that assigns indices to the teams. You would need that to create your opponents column,

Comment: if I upload the data set, the one in picture 1, would you please try and do it? I'm relatively new to R, and this has been an absolute struggle. @RajeshS

Answer (score 0):

I can't thoroughly test it without a sample of your data or something like it, but I think this would do the job.

```
# Create a function to get win and loss counts by season for a single team
teamsum <- function(teamname) {
  require(dplyr)
  df <- practice %>%
    # Reduce the data set to games involving a single team
    filter(AWAY TEAM==teamname | HOME TEAM==teamname) %>%
    # Create a 0/1 indicator for whether or not that team won each of those games. Note
    # that ties will get treated as losses here; you could change that with a more
    # complicated set of if/else statements
    mutate(team = teamname,
       win = ifelse((AWAY TEAM==teamname & AWAY SCORE > HOME SCORE) |
        (HOME TEAM==teamname & HOME SCORE > AWAY SCORE), 1, 0)) %>%
    # Group the data by season for the summing to follow
    group_by(SEASON) %>%
    # Reduce the data to a table with counts of wins and losses by season
    summarise(wins = sum(win),
      losses = n() - sum(win)) %>%
    # Add the team name as an id column to that summary table. In dplyr piping, '.' is
    # the object created by the preceding step in the pipeline -- here, that summary
    # table of wins and losses.
    cbind(team = rep(teamname, nrow(.)), .) %>%
  return(df)
}

# Apply that function to a vector of unique team names to make a list with
# tables of win & loss counts by season for each team in the original data.
# This version assumes that every team was the home team at least once.
teamlist <- lapply(unique(practice[,"HOME TEAM"]), teamsum)

# Merge the elements of that list into a single data frame. You could rbind, too.
df <- Reduce(function(...) merge(...), teamlist)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was able to use the lists and rbind them into one big data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Another *dplyr* answer

I used your code to get the dataset and then I duplicated the team columns to use as key for reshaping the dataset, you can probably use the same concept to achieve the objective in base R.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

practice_2 <- practice %>%
  mutate(home = `HOME TEAM`,
         away = `AWAY TEAM`) %>% 
  # transform dataset to long format with `tidyr::gather()`
  gather(LOC, TEAM, 6:7) %>% 
  group_by(SEASON, TEAM) %>%
  mutate(won  = ifelse(LOC == "home",
                      as.numeric(`HOME SCORE` >  `AWAY SCORE`),
                      as.numeric(`AWAY SCORE` >  `HOME SCORE`)),
         lost = ifelse(LOC == "home",
                      as.numeric(`HOME SCORE` <= `AWAY SCORE`),
                      as.numeric(`AWAY SCORE` <= `HOME SCORE`)),
         op = ifelse(LOC == "home", `AWAY TEAM`, `HOME TEAM`)) %>% 
  summarise(WINS   = sum(won, na.rm = TRUE),
            LOSSES = sum(lost, na.rm = TRUE),
            OPPONENTS = list(unique(op)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! It put me on the right track!